# drawing clicks on a responsive page comes wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I  built a simple tracker that records the X and Y for each click on an .html page then a function that draws the clicks which work great, the problem is when I resize the screen then well... everything gets messed up of course.
I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to do this ? 
I was thinking about implementing something with .resize :

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var r_width = $( window ).width();
});
```

To calculate the width of the window then use it ? any ideas or suggestions? kind of stuck and trying to keep moving forward. thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Can you show us the function that draws the clicks?

Comment: it's pretty long I can write the code if I have an idea on where to start. or any short snippet that will help I ll write the rest thanks @LcSalazar

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a canvas that represents your browser window.

First, let's clarify the formula to translate window coordinates (from clicks) to canvas coordinates (drawing position).  This would be something like:

> canvasX = windowX / windowWidth * canvasWidth;
>
> canvasY = windowY / windowHeight * canvasHeight;

So if your window changes size (windowWidth & windowHeigth have changed) you have two options:

1.) Change the size of your canvas proportionally to the change of the window size

- Capture the original window size in a global variable.
- In your resize event handler, calculate the percent change new / old.
- Change your canvas size by this percentage.

2.) Scale the contents of your canvas

- Capture the original window size in a global variable.
- In your resize event handler, calculate the percent change new / old.
- Copy current canvas content to image or another canvas
- clear your canvas
- draw the copied content back onto the canvas using the [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#scale()) method